# How to mock jest function and expect mocked result to be passed?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

Trying to mock jest functions to expect fakeReturn to be passed but it throws this error 
`{"balanceAccount": "4120.28", "lob": "Retail", "payment": {"achAuthRequiredInd": "false", "recentPaymentAmount": "", "recentPaymentIndicator": "false"}}
as argument 1, but it was called with "Cannot read property 'StatusDescription' of undefined".` that is not even declared in fakeResponse. Any help here ?

main.spec.ts

```
const fakeReturnResponse = {
    header: {
        "statusCode": "9999",
        "statusDesc": "partial failure",
        "IndexOfRequestThatFailed": [
            1
        ]
    },
    details: [
        {
            "lob": "Retail",
            "balanceAccount": "4120.28",
            "payment": {
                "recentPaymentIndicator": "false",
                "recentPaymentAmount": "",
                "achAuthRequiredInd": "false"
            }
        }
    ]
};

const controller = GetAccountBalanceController;
const reqSPL: any =  {
    body: {
            // Request body
        }

};
makeRequest.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(fakeReturnResponse));
const res: any = {};
res.send = jest.fn();
res.status = jest.fn();

describe('getBalance for Retail Response', function() {
    beforeEach(function(done) {
        controller.process(reqSPL, res).then(function() {
            done();
        });

    });
    describe('Retail', function() {
        it('res.send should be called once', function() {
            expect(res.send.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);
        });

        it('res.send ', function() {
            // The first argument of the first call to the function
            expect(res.send).details[0](fakeReturnResponse);

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: the error message makes it look like your mocking of `req` and `res` is insufficient, and you need to add `StatusDescription`.

Comment: `expect(res.send).details[0](fakeReturnResponse);` is not correct. Please update.